# date_trunc function in jpql query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am really stuck with date_trunc funtion in JPQL.

My query is:

```
@Query("SELECT c.name AS name, SUM(c.salary) AS salary FROM SalaryTable AS c GROUP BY c.name, date_trunc('year' c.savedtimestamp)")
```

I get the exception:

has 'date_trunc' and '('year' c.savedtimestamp)' that are not separated by a comma.\n[197, 203] The identification variable ''year'' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.","\tat org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:157)","\tat org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:336)","\tat org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:280)","\tat

Can you help me in this regard ?

Regards,
Stephan

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

`date_trunc('year', c.savedtimestamp)`

Note the ',' per the error message"

`has 'date_trunc' and '('year' c.savedtimestamp)' that are not separated by a comma`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I have put comma ',' I still have following exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: \nException Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT c.name AS name, SUM(c.salary) AS salary FROM SalaryTable AS c GROUP BY c.name, date_trunc('year', c.savedtimestamp)]. \n[195, 196] ...... has 'date_trunc' and '('year', c.savedtimestamp)' that are not separated by a comma.\n[197, 203] The identification variable ''year'' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.","\tat org.eclipse.persistenc –

Comment: Sorry i copied earlier trace.....but now i copied corrected one... still exception occurs

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it wants ```date_trunc``` and ```('year', c.savedtimestamp)``` separated by a comma. That does not make sense, unless it is related to: ```identification variable ''year'' is not following the rules for a Java identifier```. You might want to try using ''year'' in the query.

Comment: can you please elaborate your idea ? Sorry, i am not so much expert in JPA.

Comment: Neither am I (: I originally thought this was due the obvious syntax error of no ','  between 'year' and c.savedtimestamp. It seems to be related to the use of ```'year'```.  My suggestion was to use ```''year''``` as an attempt to escape the ' . You might also try ```\'year\'```. These are just guesses based on escaping strategies I have used in other circumtances.  You might have to ask on a Spring-boot forum for a better solution.

Comment: I think that jpql does not support date_trunc funtion. So, i changed jpql query to native query. This native query returns List<Object[]>. To get specigied list, i created projection. With projection, i get exception: QueryException\nException Description: Missing descriptor for [interface javax.persistence.Tuple].\nQuery: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Tuple sql=\"SELECT c.name......    Do you have any idea ?

Comment: It seems jpql has some general parsing issues, not that it does not support date_trunc(). As to the other issue I have no idea. I would create another SO question to see if someone else does.

Comment: Also I would file an issue with spring-boot/spring-data-jpa on the date_trunc() problem.